# How to target multiple company shares using json in linkedin

Tags: linkedin-api

At https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/company-pages#targetting_shares, the json format of targetting_shares is as follows. I have no clue on how to target multiple share targets or a single share target with multiple values using this format. Anybody knowing about this ?

```
{
  "visibility": {
    "code": "anyone"
  },
  "comment": "Testing a full company share!",
  "content": {
    "submitted-url": "https://www.example.com/content.html",
    "title": "Test Share with Content",
    "description": "content description",
    "submitted‐image-­url": "https://www.example.com/img.jpg"
  },
  "shareTargetReach": {
    "shareTargets": {
      "shareTarget": {
        "tvalues": {
          "tvalue": "na"
        },
        "code": "geos"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the docs:

> To target a share, modify the POST body of the share request to describe the various segments and values that you want to target by defining one or more share-target elements within the share-target-reach share-targets lists.  A share-target contains a code and a list of tvalues which represent the various segment values you wish to target.

So, you just need to add new `share-target` blocks within `share-targets`, like so:

```
{
  "visibility": {
    "code": "anyone"
  },
  "comment": "Testing a full company share!",
  "content": {
    "submitted-url": "https://www.example.com/content.html",
    "title": "Test Share with Content",
    "description": "content description",
    "submitted‐image-­url": "https://www.example.com/img.jpg"
  },
  "shareTargetReach": {
    "shareTargets": {

      // 1st Share target
      "shareTarget": {
        "tvalues": {
          "tvalue": "D"    // 51-200 employees
        },
        "code": "companySizes"
      },

      // 2nd Share target
      "shareTarget": {
        "tvalues": {
          "tvalue": "edu",   // Education
          "tvalue": "finc"   // Finance
        },
        "code": "jobFunc"
      }

    }
  }
}
```

Just make sure you remove all the //-comments, which are just in there to help illustrate what's going on, and will otherwise choke a JSON parser.